# ARM Assembly: write number located on stack

Tags: assembly, arm

I have an ARM assembly code that atm just prints out "Hello World" from a string variable:

```
  .global _start

_start:
    mov r0, #40
    mov r1, #25
    bl func1
    mov r7, #1
    swi 0

func1:
    push {lr}
    add r2,r0,r1
    mov r0,r2
    bl func2
    pop {pc}

func2:
    mov r7, #4
    mov r0, #1
    mov r2, #12
    ldr r1, =string

    swi 0
    bx lr

.data
    string:
    .ascii "Hello World\n"
```

Now however, I want to print the result of the addition happening in func1 (result = 65) by writing it onto the stack and then handing the write() syscall the memory address of the result on the stack.
I have already tried pushing the result at the beginning of func2 onto the stack with

```
push {r0}
```

and then somehow loading the address of that in r1 (which stores the parameter to print for the write() syscall) by accessing the stack pointer and an offset of 4, where the value should be stored if Im correct:

```
ldr r1, [sp, #4]
```

But this doesnt seem to work, I only get segmentation faults with everything I try like this.

Can anyone help me on how I can get the memory of address on the stack of the result and then proceed to print it with the write() syscall? Im ok with it if it prints the result as a letter instead of a number (since it will probably interprete it as an ASCII value), its just about me understanding how to get the address of the value on the stack and print it.
Thx a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the address 4 bytes past `sp`, you'd do `add r1, sp, #4`. However remember that `push` uses the stack in full descending mode, meaning `sp` points to the last item pushed. As such you don't need to add `4`, you can just do `mov r1, sp`.

What you did with `ldr` was actually loading the value from the stack and even if you used the correct offset that would still not have been good as you need the address not the value.

Comment: Hm, yeah that makes sense. However, if I change the code under func2 to this


     func2:
      push {r0}
      mov r7, #4
      mov r0, #1
      mov r2, #2
      mov r1, sp

it gives me a segmentation fault (core dumped). What am I still doing wrong here?

Comment: Ah, I think it prints out an 'A' before the message of "uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped" though, so it seems to work this way :)
Why is it though, that I still get the segmentation fault, although it prints the value #65 as an ASCII value? Does this just happen everytime you access the stack pointer like this?

Comment: Of course not, the fault is elsewhere. For example, you might have forgotten to pop the value from the stack.

Comment: Why would I need to popo the value from the stack though? I just want to read it from the stack for which I need to address.
Any idea why the segmentation fault happened given my code above with the changes from my 1st comment to your initial answer?

Comment: Because your `func1` does `pop {pc}` and it will be quite unhappy to find your number there instead of the `lr` it pushed earlier. Use a debugger to pinpoint where the fault is.